# How to extend a unitary operator to a larger space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a Hilbert space with a subspace $W$. Suppose $U: W\rightarrow V$ is a linear operator which preserves inner products. Prove that there exists a unitary operator $U':V\rightarrow V$ which extends $U$.

In fact there is a solution on this site, say $U'=U\otimes I$ is the right answer. But I cannot understand what this means.

Comment: I guess you'll have to rely on a basis of $W$ and of $W^\perp$ ? or simply rely on the orthogonal projection operator on one of those.

Comment: Is $W$ closed? ${}$

Comment: @copper.hat  I think it does not matter, since according to BLT we can always extend the operator to its closure.

Comment: A solution on what site?  $U \otimes I$ is a wrong answer, except in a rather special case.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Maybe I did not look carefully...  It is on [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237885/how-to-extended-a-unitary-operator-to-a-larger-space)

Comment: Don't believe everything you see on the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false in general.

Consider the operator on $W \leq V= \ell^2 (\Bbb {N})$ with $W $ as the closed span of all $(\delta_{2n})_{n} $ given on basis elements by $U (\delta_{2n})=\delta_n $.

Then $U $ is surjective, so that any proper extension $U' : V \to V $ can not be injective and thus not unitary.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.